# Why doesn't my VirtualBox VM detect all the CPUs allocated to it?

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtualbox, cpu, boot2docker

I am trying to run the boot2docker Linux VM on a Windows 7 host with VirtualBox 5.0.6 r103037. The physical machine has 2 Intel Xeon E5-2448L processors, each with 8 physical cores:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsBFZ.png

I checked the BIOS settings and both hyperthreading and VT-x are enabled.
When I created my VM in VirtualBox, I attempted to assign it the max number of CPUs allowed (32):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY6zD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFoah.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJyPp.png

However, when I check the number of processors in the VM, I only see 8:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs1Cv.png

Any ideas on what I need to do so that the VM gets all the CPUs I assign to it?

Comment: Sorry about not embedding the images in the post; it kept complaining about detecting code in my post even though there was none and the only way I could get it to post was if I took out the image Markdown